# How to have multiple one to one relations to a specific model

Tags: django

I have a scientific info model that has a one-to-one relationship to my User model.
this is my model:

```
class ScientificInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    **other fields**
```

I want to add an interviewer field to it as well so that I can chose an interviewer from the user model so I added it like this:

```
class ScientificInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    interviewer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='interviews')
    **other fields**
```

but when I want to create a new user it gives me unique constraint failed error

Comment: Likely `interviewer` should be a `ForeignKey`, otherwise all people are interviewed by *different* users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `OneToOneField` because you're using two relations with the same table. You'd better use `ForeignKey`.

```
class ScientificInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')
    interviewer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='interviews')
    **other fields**
```

Comment: it gives me this error after doing this: The row in table 'reg_scientificinfo' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: reg_scientificinfo.interviewer_id contains a value '' that does not have a corresponding value in reg_user.id.

Comment: Wait a minute, why did you set `id` field? Django supports the default primary key, so you don't need to set that field. Please remove `id` field in all models.

Comment: I did but it still gives me the same error

Comment: And please remove all migration files previously created, create a new database, and make migration files and migrate again. Then I think it should work.

Comment: now it gives me this: NOT NULL constraint failed: reg_scientificinfo.interviewer_id

Comment: I think you're still using the old database, aren't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244735/discussion-between-sam-and-metalgear).